# Polyfill for the new CSS size units

Tags: html, css, polyfills

So I was looking at the new size units in CSS namely `dvh` and `dvw` both of which felt extremely useful and so I went ahead and used them in my application but now comes the question of what about older browser versions that do not support these features?

In my website testing, I tried the website on many different devices and found that the support for these new units is a lot less than I had initially imagined, one in four mobiles do not support dynamic port sizing, is there a polyfill that can help on older browsers? probably one that can adjust to the viewport size like `dvh` and `dvw`?

Comment: You should bookmark this site (and try a little research effort, it is the first site that will come up): https://caniuse.com/?search=dvh

Comment: I was asking for a polyfill, but so far I have not seen one. Do let me know if you see a polyfill.

Comment: Same concern. It's a tradeoff for using this API: Work on new versions of browser but can be broken in older versions.
I came across https://www.npmjs.com/package/large-small-dynamic-viewport-units-polyfill, but I can't assure it's reliable.